# Extracting string between two characters or string using mysql REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: mysql, regex

I need help in extracting the following string. I have tried many solutions but this one is the closest. But still not what I require. Any help is appreciated.

Sample URL: `'https://mywebsite/path/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=123abc'`

Required Result:

| utm_source | utm_medium | gclid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| google | cpc | 123abc |

The following example for gclid gives me **gclid=123abc** as a result, while I require to extract **123abc**

```
SELECT l.url, REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, 'gclid=([^&]*)') as data
FROM mydatabase.mytable AS l
WHERE Date(l.registration_date) >= '2021-06-15'
AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, 'gclid=([^&]*)') is not null
```

I need to parse the other two fields also like utm_source and utm_medium.

Comment: You can try `REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, '(?<=[?&]gclid=)[^&#]+')` and similarly `REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, '(?<=[?&]utm_source=)[^&#]+')` and `REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, '(?<=[?&]utm_medium=)[^&#]+')`

Comment: `gclid=12345` in sample URL but `gclid=123abc` in required output. Typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehinds here to exclude the static text from your matches:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, '(?<=[?&]gclid=)[^&#]+')
REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, '(?<=[?&]utm_source=)[^&#]+')
REGEXP_SUBSTR(l.url, '(?<=[?&]utm_medium=)[^&#]+')
```

See a [sample regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gblmue/1).

*Details*:

- `(?<=[?&]gclid=)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `?` or `&` (this makes sure we only match the full query param key) and then `gclid=`
- `[^&#]+` - one or more chars other than `&` and `#` (consumed and returned as a match value).

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> SET @URL := 'https://mywebsite/path/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&gclid=12345';
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@URL, 'utm_source=', -1), '&', 1) utm_source,
>        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@URL, 'utm_medium=', -1), '&', 1) utm_medium,
>        SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@URL, 'gclid=', -1), '&', 1) gclid;
> ```
>
> | utm_source | utm_medium | gclid |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | google | cpc | 12345 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9f14e9ebb2fd17dccdc6abfd350f687f)*